# How to horizontally position my dynamic width image

Tags: html, css

Im having a hard time centering my image which does not have a fixed width, as I will be swapping it out with others of different sizes. I dont want it to go over 390px high, that's why I have it set with a max-height. I have tried numerous things such as margin: 0 auto; text align centering it with inline display and making the div a table as suggesting on this site for similar problems. Can anyone help? Thanks.

fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/vcrensuq/

```
html:

<div class="wrapper"> 

<div class="block" id="flip-block">
<div class="front side">
<img src="http://imgur.com/etY8veW.jpg">
 </div>
<div class="back side">
<img src="http://imgur.com/DiSXWpR.jpg">
</div>
</div>

css:

.block {
position: relative;
height: 410px;
width: 582px;
text-align: center;
}

.block img { max-width: 580px;
max-height: 390px;
display: inline-block;


}
```

Comment: Your title talk about Horizontally center but you mention `max-height` so....height is vertical

Comment: I was just specifying why i had a max- width and max-height in my code. I am looking to center my image horizontally while fitting in a max-height container.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're wrapping the images in a DIV you should apply auto margins to it:

```
div.side 
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by adding:

```
.block { margin: 0 auto; }
.side { position: relative;
       display: inline block; }
```

To prevent the lower div from showing upon flipping, I added :

```
.back { top: -409px;}
```

My updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vcrensuq/3/